# Always Encryption Not Working with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2016

I am using Always Encrypt option in Sql 2016. I have connected SQL with entity framework using MVC application. I have encrypted the column as described in below link. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110564/Always-Encrypted-feature-in-SQL-Server
I can able to insert the data using insert query via entity framework. But I can't able to insert the data using stored procedure.

Table details are below.

```
create table Team(Id int not null primary key identity, Name nvarchar(100))
```

Note: If we change the column length as nvarchar(max) the stored procedure works fine.

We have an existing database. We should not alter anything in the existing database. What is the best way to use Always encryption without affecting existing database structure for GDPR compliance?

Code Sample

**Stored Procedure**

```
USE [EncryptTest]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Team]
    @full_name nvarchar(100) 
    As
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Team (Name)
    VALUES  (@full_name)
END
```

**Working**

```
using (var cont = new EncryptTestEntities())
            {
                Teamt = new EncrypTTest.Team();
                t.Name = "Melody";
                t.Email = "melody@gmail.com";
                cont.Teams.Add(t); 
                cont.SaveChanges();
            }
```

**Not Working**

```
using (var cont = new EncryptTestEntities())
            {

                cont.Insert_Team("Melody");
            }
```

**Error when inserting data via stored procedure**

```
Operand type clash: nvarchar(4000) encrypted with
(encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 
'Algorithm Name', column_encryption_key_name = 'keyName', 
column_encryption_key_database_name = 'SampleEncryption') is 
incompatible with nvarchar(100) encrypted with (encryption_type = 
'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'Algorithm Name', 
column_encryption_key_name = 'keyName', 
column_encryption_key_database_name = 'SampleEncryption')
```

Comment: Right, so you've uncovered a bug in your application where currently you allow a `nvarchar(4000)` in through a stored procedure despite the table only being able to accommodate an `nvarchar(100)`. Now that you're using encryption, the system cannot continue to support this mismatch in data sizes. If it's *that important to you that the existing bug remains*, then you cannot have encryption. Otherwise, you do need to make changes so that you no longer have the bug. Which way you go is your decision, of course...

Comment: I cant get you exactly. Can you explain bit more about this? My question is SP only throwing exception. But i can able to insert using insert query

Comment: You are able to insert using a query because you probably are not defining your column for an insert. The engine would *implicitly infer* the type automatically. Since you have defined the procedure input as `nvarchar(100)` that is *explicitly incorrect* now.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Stored procedure to support Always encryption you have to make sure following thing int the creating Stored procedure

1. Data type and size of the parameter of the Stored procedure should be as same as column of the table
   Ex: Data type and size of parameter **@full_name** should be as same as column Name
2. You have to re-assign the parameter values to new parameter and use the new parameter for the SP as below example.
   Ex:

   ```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Team]
       @full_name nvarchar(100) 
       As
   BEGIN

   DECLARE @full_name_ nvarchar(100)  = @full_name
       INSERT INTO Team (Name)
       VALUES  (@full_name_)
   END
   ```